# hide some table row according to multiple checkbox selection with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have 2 tables like this with some checkbox for filter the table:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_filter_Grocery_1" id="chk_filter_Grocery_1_1" value="1;">Alamond</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_filter_Grocery_1" id="chk_filter_Grocery_1_2" value="14;">Apple</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_filter_Grocery_1" id="chk_filter_Grocery_1_3" value="5;6;">Lemon & Orange</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_filter_Grocery_1" id="chk_filter_Grocery_1_4" value="17;">Coconut</label>

<table width="620px" id="Grocery-NA768">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="14">
            <td width="185" height="35" align="left">Apple</td>
            <td width="65" height="35" align="center" valign="middle">3 Kg</td>
            <td width="80" height="35" align="center" valign="middle">28/07/2011</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="5">
            <td height="35" align="left">Lemon</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">5 Kg</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">28/07/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="17">
            <td height="35" align="left">Coconut</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">4 Kg</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">28/07/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="14">
            <td height="35" align="left">Apple</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">2 Kg</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">27/04/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="1">
            <td height="35" align="left">Almond</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">3 Kg</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">27/04/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="6">
            <td height="35" align="left">Orange</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">3 kg</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">27/04/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_filter_Wine_1" id="chk_filter_Wine_1_1" value="51;">Brunello di Montalcino</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_filter_Wine_1" id="chk_filter_Wine_1_2" value="4;">Dolcetto</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_filter_Wine_1" id="chk_filter_Wine_1_3" value="35;64;">Pinot noir & Pinot blanc</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk_filter_Wine_1" id="chk_filter_Wine_1_4" value="72;">Shiraz </label>
<table width="620px" id="Wine-NA768">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="4">
            <td width="185" height="35" align="left">Dolcetto</td>
            <td width="65" height="35" align="center" valign="middle">3 b</td>
            <td width="80" height="35" align="center" valign="middle">28/07/2011</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="35">
            <td height="35" align="left">Pinot blanc</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">5 b.</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">28/07/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="72">
            <td height="35" align="left">Shiraz</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">4 b.</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">28/07/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="14">
            <td height="35" align="left">Dolcetto</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">2 b.</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">27/04/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="51">
            <td height="35" align="left">Brunello di Montalcino</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">3 b.</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">27/04/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="64">
            <td height="35" align="left">Pinot noir</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">3 b.</td>
            <td height="35" align="center" valign="middle">27/04/2011&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The two table have a different id (Grocery-NA768) and (Wine-NA768) and each checkbox has one or more (max 2) value (1;12;) and every  of the table has the corresponding number as class.

I would like to filter the table clicking on the checkbox. I.e. when I click the apple checkbox (value 14) I want to see only the apple in the table (class 14), then if I click on the citrus (value 1;12;) checkbox I will see apple (class 14), lemon (class 5)and orange. If I deselect all the checkbox I will see the whole list.
Same thing for the wine table. I site new of jquery and I've found how to show or hide table row clicking on a checkbox but nothing similar to my needs.

Thanks in advance
Michele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/6dNKA/3/

See comments in the code:

```
// Define some config objects and loop over them to get things set up
$.each([{
    table: $("#Grocery-NA768"),
    inputs: $("input[name='chk_filter_Grocery_1']")
},{
    table: $("#Wine-NA768"),
    inputs: $("input[name='chk_filter_Wine_1']")
}],function(i, obj){
    var list = [];
    obj.inputs.click(function() {
        var that = $(this),
            value = that.val().match(/\d+/g),
            rows = obj.table.find("tr");

        // If its checked then add it to the list
        if ( that.prop("checked") ) {
            list = $.merge(list, value);
        } else {
            // if its not then remove the items from the list
            list = $.map( list, function( x ) {
                return ( $.inArray( x, value ) > -1 ) ? null : x;
            });
        }
        // If the list has items
        if ( list.length ) {
            rows.hide() // hide all rows
                .filter("."+list.join(",.")) // find the ones we care about
                .show(); // and show them
        } else {
            // If no items in the list
            rows.show(); // show every row
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Michele please mark it as the correct answer if it help you or at least vote up. :)

Comment: @Michele that's ok. Welcome to stackoverflow :D